# regular expression: extract number in an expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following expression:

```
"1+3x+52-9-45x+x"
```

my goal is to extract all the constants:
[1,+52,-9]

I have tried using Python:

```
re.findall("[+-]?\d+","1+3x+52-9-45x+x")
```

Result is:

> ['1', '+3', '+52', '-9', '-45']

which are not correct because the coefficents of x are also extracted.

I also tried:

```
re.findall("[+-]?\d+[+-]?","1+3x+52-9-45x+x")
```

But still not working.

Comment: Where is the "-3" in your sampe input and why do you not expect the "-9"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
(?:[+-])?\b\d+\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UH0OKB/4)

OR

```
(?:[+-])?\d+(?=[\s+-]|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UH0OKB/6)

**Explanation(for the 1st Regex):**

- `(?:[+-])` Matching Either a `+` or a `-`(Add more operators if you want)
- `?` Making `+` or `-` optional
- `\b\d+\b` matching 1 or more digits between 2 non-words(so it will not include the coefficients)

**Explanation(for the 2nd Regex):**

- `(?:[+-])` Matching Either a `+` or a `-`(Add more operators if you want)
- `?` Making `+` or `-` optional
- `\d+(?=[+-])` matching 1 or more digits(greedy) immediately followed by a `+` or `-` or a space or If it is the end of line. You can add more operators if you want.

Comment: I tried: re.findall("(?:[+-])?\b\d+\b","1+3x+52-9-45x+x"). but got empty. Am I missing anything herer?

Comment: I got it. Do NOT forget to use raw string marker "r" before your pattern. re.findall(r"(?:[+-])?\b\d+\b","1+3x+52-9-45x+x"). This works perfectly1